# Javascript: Open new window and send the result back to parent window

Tags: javascript, window

On many pages you can log in with google. When you click the button, a new window is opened where you can enter your e-mail and password. After successful login the window closes automatically and the old window receives the login token. How does this technically work? How is the result from the google login window send to the old window?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a relationship between the browser windows that is maintained. In the child window (the popup), for instance, you can send a message to the window that created it

```
window.opener.postMessage("a message");
```

How this is implemented can vary, but the basic answer to your question is that your browser is just keeping track of the windows relationship and allowing messages (i.e. commands, tokens, etc.) to be passed between them.

[Mozzila postMessage reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you can help me with a second similiar question. Is there a way to open a browser window from a deskop application and communicate between the browser window and the desktop application?